# ImportError: cannot import name check_array from sklearn.utils.validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

When I import the function `check_array` from module `sklearn.utils.validation`, it got an Import Error (`ImportError: cannot import name check_array`).
The tab completion got `check_arrays`, but I'm wondering there only exists a function called `check_array` in `validation.py` ( [source code on Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py)).
Besides, the spectral clustering algorithm implemented in [scikit-learn/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py) also used `from ..utils.validation import check_array`, not `check_arrays`.
I'm quite confused about this, and my scikit-learn version is `'0.15.0b1'`. Hope somebody gives me a clue.

sample code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
def my_fit_affinity(X, affinity_type, n_neighbors, **kernel_params):
    """ Create an affinity matrix for X using the selected affinity type
    """    
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse = ['csr', 'csc', 'coo']) 
    ....
    return affinity_matrix_
```

Comment: Shortest code sample to reproduce your error, please.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo I've added sample code

Comment: This has recently changed. So it is probably a version issue. Make sure you are on the latest one and that there are no residual files of the preceding ones anywhere.

Comment: @eickenberg thanks and I've fixed this problem~

Comment: meaning that it works now or does the problem persist / has it changed in nature?

Comment: @eickenberg the problem still exists but using `check_arrays` achieved the same purpose

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I am getting a vary similar one.

Comment: @amaatouq using `check_arrays` instead of `check_array` may work

Answer (score 16):

If you use jupyter notebook, try restarting your kernel.

Answer (score 2):

To those searching, as @eickenberg mentioned in the comments, this was something that was changed between versions. Using the latest version of `scikit-learn` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hit kernel > restart and run all

Comment: Restarting the kernel was already mentioned in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59553425/2745495).