# Jupyter Notebook: Importing SMOTE from imblearn - ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise_distances_chunked'

Tags: python, jupyter, imblearn

I'm trying to use the `SMOTE` package in the `imblearn` library using:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

getting the following error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise_distances_chunked'.

Here is a screenshot  of my import [screenshot of download confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB82f.png)

Really stumped on this, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have encountered a similar problem.
I could solve by opening a new IPython console.

Comment: It finally worked for me too once I closed and re-opened Jupyter notebook. A bit of an odd dynamic but I guess that's the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but for anyone using Jupyter notebook, I could solve my problem by just restarting the kernel.

Link:

[ImportError: cannot import name check_array from sklearn.utils.validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173030/importerror-cannot-import-name-check-array-from-sklearn-utils-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the package solved the issue.

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Answer (score -1):

I opened a new console after re-install Scikit-learn 
(`python3 -m pip install -U scikit-learn`; in Jupyter notebook), then it works.