# cannot import name 'SMOTEN' from 'imblearn.over_sampling'

Tags: python, jupyter, imbalanced-data, imblearn, smote

SMOTE and SMOTENC is working. But unable to use SMOTEN.
I tried solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881187/jupyter-notebook-importing-smote-from-imblearn-importerror-cannot-import-nam). But still only for SMOTEN it returns the error,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SMOTEN' from 'imblearn.over_sampling'.
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook and below is the snippet of error returned.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-222dc3b0b449> in <module>
      1 #import imblearn library
----> 2 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved after upgrading to Version 0.8.0 of Imbalanced-Learn. Because I found updations in imbalanced-learn releases of [SMOTEN](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/releases)

Previous version I had:

```
import imblearn
print("Imbalanced-Learn", imblearn.__version__)
Imbalanced-Learn 0.7.0
```

Now SMOTEN is working after upgrading to Imbalanced-Learn 0.8.0