# Plot dendrogram using sklearn.AgglomerativeClustering

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I'm trying to build a dendrogram using the `children_` attribute provided by `AgglomerativeClustering`, but so far I'm out of luck. I can't use `scipy.cluster` since agglomerative clustering provided in `scipy` lacks some options that are important to me (such as the option to specify the amount of clusters). I would be really grateful for a any advice out there.

```
    import sklearn.cluster
    clstr = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2)
    clusterer.children_
```

Comment: Please post a code sample to enlarge the chances of getting good answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851553/sklearn-agglomerative-clustering-linkage-matrix)

Answer (score 23):

Here is a [simple function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/70cf4a676caa2d2dad2e3f6e4478d64bcb0506f7/examples/cluster/plot_hierarchical_clustering_dendrogram.py) for taking a hierarchical clustering model from sklearn and plotting it using the scipy `dendrogram` function. Seems like graphing functions are often not directly supported in sklearn. You can find an interesting discussion of that related to the pull request for this `plot_dendrogram` code snippet [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3464).

I'd clarify that the use case you describe (defining number of clusters) is available in scipy: after you've performed the hierarchical clustering using scipy's `linkage` you can cut the hierarchy to whatever number of clusters you want using `fcluster` with number of clusters specified in the `t` argument and `criterion='maxclust'` argument.

Answer (score 20):

Use the scipy implementation of agglomerative clustering instead. Here is an example.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

data = [[0., 0.], [0.1, -0.1], [1., 1.], [1.1, 1.1]]

Z = linkage(data)

dendrogram(Z)
```

You can find documentation for `linkage` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) and documentation for `dendrogram` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html).

Comment: This answer is useful because it points out an alternative way of creating and visualizing a hierarchical clustering via scipy, so I upvoted it.  However this doesn't answer the original question, which was about how to visualize the dendrogram of a clustering created by *scikit-learn*.  It would be great if you added a function that took scikit-learn's output and created a data structure like Z.

Comment: @conradlee actually that's what the `plot_dendrogram()` function does here --all but the last line: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html And the `dendrogram` function called in the last line is imported from `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`

Comment: @tozCSS Thanks for pointing that out.  The answer that's now highest-voted does indeed answer the question by linking to the `plot_dendrogram` snippet that's now part of the scikit-learn docs.  I'm glad to see the docs have improved.  I've now removed my upvote here.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the exact same problem some time ago. The way I managed to plot the damn dendogram was using the software package [ete3](http://etetoolkit.org/). This package is able to flexibly plot trees with various options. The only difficulty was to convert `sklearn`'s `children_` output to the [Newick Tree format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format) that can be read and understood by `ete3`. Furthermore, I need to manually compute the dendrite's span because that information was not provided with the `children_`. Here is a snippet of the code I used. It computes the Newick tree and then shows the `ete3` Tree datastructure. For more details on how to plot, take a look [here](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import ete3

def build_Newick_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,spanner):
    """
    build_Newick_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,spanner)

    Get a string representation (Newick tree) from the sklearn
    AgglomerativeClustering.fit output.

    Input:
        children: AgglomerativeClustering.children_
        n_leaves: AgglomerativeClustering.n_leaves_
        X: parameters supplied to AgglomerativeClustering.fit
        leaf_labels: The label of each parameter array in X
        spanner: Callable that computes the dendrite's span

    Output:
        ntree: A str with the Newick tree representation

    """
    return go_down_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,len(children)+n_leaves-1,spanner)[0]+';'

def go_down_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,nodename,spanner):
    """
    go_down_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,nodename,spanner)

    Iterative function that traverses the subtree that descends from
    nodename and returns the Newick representation of the subtree.

    Input:
        children: AgglomerativeClustering.children_
        n_leaves: AgglomerativeClustering.n_leaves_
        X: parameters supplied to AgglomerativeClustering.fit
        leaf_labels: The label of each parameter array in X
        nodename: An int that is the intermediate node name whos
            children are located in children[nodename-n_leaves].
        spanner: Callable that computes the dendrite's span

    Output:
        ntree: A str with the Newick tree representation

    """
    nodeindex = nodename-n_leaves
    if nodename<n_leaves:
        return leaf_labels[nodeindex],np.array([X[nodeindex]])
    else:
        node_children = children[nodeindex]
        branch0,branch0samples = go_down_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,node_children[0])
        branch1,branch1samples = go_down_tree(children,n_leaves,X,leaf_labels,node_children[1])
        node = np.vstack((branch0samples,branch1samples))
        branch0span = spanner(branch0samples)
        branch1span = spanner(branch1samples)
        nodespan = spanner(node)
        branch0distance = nodespan-branch0span
        branch1distance = nodespan-branch1span
        nodename = '({branch0}:{branch0distance},{branch1}:{branch1distance})'.format(branch0=branch0,branch0distance=branch0distance,branch1=branch1,branch1distance=branch1distance)
        return nodename,node

def get_cluster_spanner(aggClusterer):
    """
    spanner = get_cluster_spanner(aggClusterer)

    Input:
        aggClusterer: sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering instance

    Get a callable that computes a given cluster's span. To compute
    a cluster's span, call spanner(cluster)

    The cluster must be a 2D numpy array, where the axis=0 holds
    separate cluster members and the axis=1 holds the different
    variables.

    """
    if aggClusterer.linkage=='ward':
        if aggClusterer.affinity=='euclidean':
            spanner = lambda x:np.sum((x-aggClusterer.pooling_func(x,axis=0))**2)
    elif aggClusterer.linkage=='complete':
        if aggClusterer.affinity=='euclidean':
            spanner = lambda x:np.max(np.sum((x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=2))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='l1' or aggClusterer.affinity=='manhattan':
            spanner = lambda x:np.max(np.sum(np.abs(x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:]),axis=2))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='l2':
            spanner = lambda x:np.max(np.sqrt(np.sum((x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=2)))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='cosine':
            spanner = lambda x:np.max(np.sum((x[:,None,:]*x[None,:,:]))/(np.sqrt(np.sum(x[:,None,:]*x[:,None,:],axis=2,keepdims=True))*np.sqrt(np.sum(x[None,:,:]*x[None,:,:],axis=2,keepdims=True))))
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Unknown affinity attribute value {0}.'.format(aggClusterer.affinity))
    elif aggClusterer.linkage=='average':
        if aggClusterer.affinity=='euclidean':
            spanner = lambda x:np.mean(np.sum((x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=2))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='l1' or aggClusterer.affinity=='manhattan':
            spanner = lambda x:np.mean(np.sum(np.abs(x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:]),axis=2))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='l2':
            spanner = lambda x:np.mean(np.sqrt(np.sum((x[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=2)))
        elif aggClusterer.affinity=='cosine':
            spanner = lambda x:np.mean(np.sum((x[:,None,:]*x[None,:,:]))/(np.sqrt(np.sum(x[:,None,:]*x[:,None,:],axis=2,keepdims=True))*np.sqrt(np.sum(x[None,:,:]*x[None,:,:],axis=2,keepdims=True))))
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Unknown affinity attribute value {0}.'.format(aggClusterer.affinity))
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Unknown linkage attribute value {0}.'.format(aggClusterer.linkage))
    return spanner

clusterer = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2,compute_full_tree=True) # You can set compute_full_tree to 'auto', but I left it this way to get the entire tree plotted
clusterer.fit(X) # X for whatever you want to fit
spanner = get_cluster_spanner(clusterer)
newick_tree = build_Newick_tree(clusterer.children_,clusterer.n_leaves_,X,leaf_labels,spanner) # leaf_labels is a list of labels for each entry in X
tree = ete3.Tree(newick_tree)
tree.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For those willing to step out of Python and use the robust D3 library, it's not super difficult to use the `d3.cluster()` (or, I guess, `d3.tree()`) APIs to achieve a nice, customizable result.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/2340/) for a demo.

The `children_` array luckily functions easily as a JS array, and the only intermediary step is to use `d3.stratify()` to turn it into a hierarchical representation. Specifically, we need each node to have an `id` and a `parentId`:

```js
var N = 272;  // Your n_samples/corpus size.
var root = d3.stratify()
  .id((d,i) => i + N)
  .parentId((d, i) => {
    var parIndex = data.findIndex(e => e.includes(i + N));
    if (parIndex < 0) {
      return; // The root should have an undefined parentId.
    }
    return parIndex + N;
  })(data); // Your children_
```

You end up with at least O(n^2) behaviour here due to the `findIndex` line, but it probably doesn't matter until your n_samples becomes huge, in which case, you could precompute a more efficient index.

Beyond that, it's pretty much plug and chug use of `d3.cluster()`. See mbostock's [canonical block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570) or my JSFiddle.

N.B. For my use case, it sufficed merely to show non-leaf nodes; it's a bit trickier to visualise the samples/leaves, since these might not all be in the `children_` array explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

From [the official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html):

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


def plot_dendrogram(model, **kwargs):
    # Create linkage matrix and then plot the dendrogram

    # create the counts of samples under each node
    counts = np.zeros(model.children_.shape[0])
    n_samples = len(model.labels_)
    for i, merge in enumerate(model.children_):
        current_count = 0
        for child_idx in merge:
            if child_idx < n_samples:
                current_count += 1  # leaf node
            else:
                current_count += counts[child_idx - n_samples]
        counts[i] = current_count

    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack([model.children_, model.distances_,
                                      counts]).astype(float)

    # Plot the corresponding dendrogram
    dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# setting distance_threshold=0 ensures we compute the full tree.
model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=0, n_clusters=None)

model = model.fit(X)
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
# plot the top three levels of the dendrogram
plot_dendrogram(model, truncate_mode='level', p=3)
plt.xlabel("Number of points in node (or index of point if no parenthesis).")
plt.show()
```

Note that this currently (as of scikit-learn v0.23) only will work when calling AgglomerativeClustering with the `distance_threshold` parameter, but as of v0.24 you will be able to force the calculation of distances by setting `compute_distances` to true ([see nightly build docs](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html)).

Comment: ValueError: Exactly one of n_clusters and distance_threshold has to be set, and the other needs to be None.   The scikit-learn version is 0.24.2.